# Colors for sections with list doesn't work for section 0

Tags: color, lists

As you can see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444078/changing-color-of-keywords-theorems-and-more-with-each-section), I wanted to color in sections of my lecture notes, meaning that the theorems, headings etc. would have a different color each section. 
I now use the proposed

```
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{,}
\readlist\mycolors{red,green,blue,purple,yellow}
```

And use something like color = \mycolors[\thesection]in my header, theorem etc definitions. 
For my current lecture notes, I want to have a chapter -1 and 0.
-1 works perfectly, since the last entry of the list is used for colouring, but the 0th entry is not defined, and the package documentation didn't help me either.

Comment: Try defining a command `\def\mthesection{\ifnum\thesection<0 \thesection\else\numexpr\thesection+1\relax\fi}` and use this inside `\mycolors` like `\mycolors[\mthesection]`

Comment: @koleygr if I use that, the produced error is: ! You can't use `\numexpr' in restricted horizontal mode. Also, the chapter names now are (without trying to achieve chapter - 1 and 0)  a + 1. And not in the sense that chapter 2 became chapter 3 but, it literally says chapter 1+1.

Comment: I added an answer that will possibly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=subsection]{mytheo1}{Satz}
{{colback=\mycolors[\mthesection]!5},{colframe=\mycolors[\mthesection]!35!black},fonttitle=\scshape\bfseries}{th}
\setsepchar{,}
\readlist\mycolors{red,green,blue,purple,yellow}
\let\oldsection\section
\def\mthesection{\ifnum\thesection<0 \thesection\else\numexpr\thesection+1\relax\fi}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\color{\mycolors[\mthesection]}\textbf{#1}}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\f@nch@head}{\rlap}{\color{\mycolors[\mthesection]}\rlap}{}{}
\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{\mycolors[\mthesection]}\hrule}{}{}
\patchcmd{\f@nch@foot}{\rlap}{\color{\mycolors[\mthesection]}\rlap}{}{}
\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{\mycolors[\mthesection]}\hrule}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{section}{-2}

\section{Pythagoras}
\begin{mytheo1}{Pythagoras}{Pythagoras}
$a^2+b^2=c^2$
\end{mytheo1}
\clearpage

\section{Fermat}
\begin{mytheo1}{Fermat}{Fermat}
$a^n+b^n=c^n$ is not possible for positive integers $a,b,c,n$ and $n>2$
\end{mytheo1}
\clearpage
\section{Something Else}
\begin{mytheo1}{Something}{Something}
$\alpha \ge 0$ if $\alpha \in N$
\end{mytheo1}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

PS: If it doesn't for you try: `\protected\def\mthesection{\ifnum\thesection<0 \thesection\else\numexpr\thesection+1\relax\fi}` and if still fails, please try to give a MWE ([I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/120578))

Comment: It also works by adding `\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{\mycolors[\mthesection]}}` (and `\usepackage{titlesec}`) before the `\begin{document}` command, and colors the section title too without your error