# Change color of equation hyperrefs with each section

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, color

Similar to two [previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444078/changing-color-of-keywords-theorems-and-more-with-each-section) [posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473298/define-bclogo-environment-that-changes-color-with-each-section) of mine, I want the color of the reference to a formula to be the same color as the theorems etc in that section.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,cancel,mathtools,framed,mathabx,array,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem} % einfacher Nummerierung verÃ¤ndern
\usepackage{tikz} % zeichnen
\usetikzlibrary{cd} % kommutierende Diagramme
\usepackage{listofitems} % fÃ¼r Farben fÃ¼r Kapitel
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo} % Kästen für Errinerung etc.

\usepackage{babel} % neue Rechtschreibung, Worttrennung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Inputencoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Umlaute

\definecolor{mycol1}{HTML}{a82337}
\definecolor{mycol2}{HTML}{016FB9}
\definecolor{mycol3}{HTML}{BF7F00}
\definecolor{mycol4}{HTML}{603C96}

% formatting
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\raggedright}
{\llap{\colorbox{mycol\number\value{section}}{\makebox[3em][r]    {\textcolor{white}{\number\value{section}}}}\hspace{1em}}}
{0pt}
{#1}


\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{first, red section}

This is the first equation
\begin{align} \label{eq:firsteqn}
\ln(e^x) = x \
\forall x \in \R
\end{align}
And here is a reference to it: \eqref{eq:firsteqn}, which should be red.

\section{next, blue section}
This is an equation
\begin{align} \label{eq:secondeqn} \tag{$\star$)}
\forall a < b < c \ \exists ! x \in \mathbb{R}: a^x + b^x = c^x.
\end{align}
And here is a reference to it: \eqref{eq:secondeqn}, which should be blue.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only referring to elements within the same section, you can switch the colour at the start of `\section`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,xcolor}

\definecolor{mycol1}{HTML}{a82337}
\definecolor{mycol2}{HTML}{016FB9}
\definecolor{mycol3}{HTML}{BF7F00}
\definecolor{mycol4}{HTML}{603C96}

% formatting
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\raggedright}
  {\llap{\colorbox{mycol\number\value{section}}{\makebox[3em][r]{\textcolor{white}{\number\value{section}}}}\hspace{1em}}}
  {0pt}
  {#1}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldsection\section
\newcommand{\updaterefcolour}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=mycol\thesection}}
\newif\ifupdaterefcolour

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{ s o m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldsection*{#3}% \section*{..}
     \def\updaterefcolour{}%
    }
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
      {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[.]{..}
      {\oldsection{#3}}% \section{..}
      \def\updaterefcolour{\hypersetup{linkcolor=mycol\thesection}}%
    }%
  \ifupdaterefcolour\updaterefcolour\fi
}

\begin{document}

\updaterefcolourfalse % Turn of reference colouring
\tableofcontents
\updaterefcolourtrue % Turn on reference colouring

\section{first, red section}

This is the first equation
\begin{equation}
  \ln(e^x) = x \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \label{eq:firsteqn}
\end{equation}
And here is a reference to it: \eqref{eq:firsteqn}, which should be red.

\section{next, blue section}
This is an equation
\begin{equation}  
  \forall a < b < c \ \exists ! x \in \mathbb{R}: a^x + b^x = c^x. \tag{$\star$} \label{eq:secondeqn}
\end{equation}
And here is a reference to it: \eqref{eq:secondeqn}, which should be blue.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks very complicated, what does it do exactly? Also, when I use a table of contents, the title appears twice and the toc is treated as section.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik: Well, you can manually add `\hypersetup{linkcolor=mycol2}` after section 2, and `\hypersetup{linkcolor=mycol3}` after section 3 and so forth. I just automated that process. That is, to insert `\hypersetup{linkcolor=mycol\thesection}` after `\section`. `\thesection` prints the number of the section, so `mycol\thesection` would be `mycol3` in section 3. Complication is added because you can use `\section*` or `\section[.]{..}` or `\section{..}`, so I've had to capture that. By the way, `\section*` would incorrectly use a successive colour, but you don't have those I presume.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik: Riiight. Okay, so you don't want that to happen with the ToC.

Comment: I don't use \section* , that is correct.

Comment: Nor with the index of list of figures etc.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik: I've updated the answer to accommodate for that. It now provides a conditional `\updaterefcolourtrue` to show references in colour and `\updaterefcolourfalse` to remove the colour reference. I've placed that around `\tableofcontents` (one could also automate that for the ToC, or other document elements). You can place it around your index and LoF/LoT as well. For every section numbered X, you would need a colour `mycolX` defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a named color it will change automatically after a \colorlet. So you only need to add a suitable colorlet at the begin of every section:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}

\definecolor{mycol1}{HTML}{a82337}
\definecolor{mycol2}{HTML}{016FB9}
\definecolor{mycol3}{HTML}{BF7F00}
\definecolor{mycol4}{HTML}{603C96}
\colorlet{sectioncolor}{mycol1}

% formatting
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}



 \titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\raggedright} 
{\llap{\colorbox{sectioncolor}{\makebox[3em][r]   
 {\textcolor{white}{\number\value{section}}}}\hspace{1em}}}
{0pt}
{#1}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=sectioncolor]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\pretocmd\section{\colorlet{sectioncolor}{mycol\the\numexpr\value{section}+1}}


\begin{document}


\section{first, red section}


This is the first equation
\begin{align} \label{eq:firsteqn}
x=y
\end{align}
And here is a reference to it: \eqref{eq:firsteqn}, which should be red.


\section{next, blue section}
This is an equation
\begin{align} \label{eq:secondeqn} 
x=y
\end{align}
And here is a reference to it: \eqref{eq:secondeqn}, which should be blue.
\end{document}
```

[image]